# How to use HBase and Hadoop to serve live traffic AND perform analytics? (Single cluster vs separate clusters?)

Tags: hadoop, analytics, live, cluster-computing, hbase

Our primary purpose is to use Hadoop for doing analytics. In this use case, we do batch processing, so throughput is more important than latency, meaning that HBase is not necessarily a good fit (although getting closer to real-time analytics does sound appealing). We are playing around with Hive and we like it so far.

Although analytics is the main thing we want to do in the immediate future with Hadoop, we are also looking to potentially migrate parts of our operations to HBase and to serve live traffic out of it. The data that would be stored there is the same data that we use in our analytics, and I wonder if we could just have one system for both live traffic and analytics.

I have read a lot of reports and it seems that most organizations choose to have separate clusters for serving traffic and for analytics. This seems like a reasonable choice for stability purposes, since we plan to have many people writing Hive queries, and badly written queries could potentially compromise the live operations.

Now my question is: how are those two different use cases reconciled (serving live traffic and doing batch analytics)? Do organizations use systems to write all data in two otherwise independent clusters? Or is it possible to do this out of the box with a single cluster in which some of the nodes serve live traffic and others do only analytics?

What I'm thinking is that we could perhaps have all data coming into the nodes that are used for serving live traffic, and let the HDFS replication mechanisms manage the copying of data into nodes that are used for analytics (increasing the replication higher than the default 3 probably makes sense in such scenario). Hadoop can be made aware of special network topologies, and it has functionality to always replicate at least one copy to different racks, so this seems to mesh well with what I'm describing.

The nodes dedicated to live traffic could be set to have zero (or few) map and reduce slots, so that all Hive queries end up being processed by the nodes dedicated to analytics.

The nodes dedicated to analytics would always be a little behind those dedicated to serving live traffic, but that does not seem to be a problem.

Does that kind of solution make sense? I am thinking it could be more simple to have one cluster than two, but would this be significantly riskier? Are there known cases of companies using a HBase cluster to serve live traffic while also running batch analytics jobs on it?

I'd love to get your opinions on this :) !

Thanks.

EDIT: What about Brisk? It's based on Cassandra instead of HBase, but it seems to be made exactly for what I'm describing (hybrid clusters). Has anyone worked with it before? Is it mature?

--
Felix

Answer (score 2):

Your approach has a few problems... even in rack aware mode, if you have more than a few racks I don't see how you can be guaranteed your nodes will be replicated on those nodes. If you lose one of your "live" nodes, then you will be under-replicated for a while and won't have access to that data.

HBase is greedy in terms of resources and I've found it doesn't play well with others (in terms of memory and CPU) in high load situations. You mention, too, that heavy analytics can impact live performance, which is also true.

In my cluster, we use Hadoop quite a bit to preprocess data for ingest into HBase. We do things like enrichment, filtering out records we don't want, transforming, summarization, etc. If you are thinking you want to do something like this, I suggest sending your data to HDFS on your Hadoop cluster first, then offloading it to your HBase cluster.

There is nothing stopping you from having your HBase cluster and Hadoop cluster on the same network backplane. I suggest instead of having hybrid nodes, just dedicate some nodes to your Hadoop cluster and some nodes to your Hbase cluster. The network transfer between the two will be quite snappy.

Just my personal experience so I'm not sure how much of it is relevant. I hope you find it useful and best of luck!

Comment: I suspected that it was probably not a good idea to use one cluster for the two activities.

I have a question about the workflow you are suggesting though. What would be the use of loading data into HDFS for doing ETL and then loading it into HBase?

You would be able to use the HBase cluster to serve live traffic for reading what's already in it, but not for random writes, since all writes would go trough HDFS first, and thus would have high latency.

So, what are you using the HBase cluster for? Just a lot of range scans and random reads? For analytics? Or for a read-heavy live workload?

Answer (score 1):

I think this kind of solution might have sense, since MR is mostly CPU intensive and HBASE is a memory hungry beast. What we do need - is to properly arrange resource management. I think it is possible in the following way: 
a) CPU. We can define maximum number of MR mappers/reducers per slot and assuming that each mapper is single threaded we can limit CPU consumption of the MR. The rest will go to HBASE. 
b) Memory.We can limit memory for mappers and reducers and the rest give to HBASE.
c) I think we can not properly manage HDFS bandwidth sharing, but I do not think it should be a problem for HBASE -since for it disk operations are not on the critical path.

Comment: Well... isn't HBase constantly writing in the HLog/WAL though?

Comment: I think what you're proposing makes sense if you have well tested batch queries which you know will not cause any problem. But to ensure that you would probably need a test cluster, so that brings us back to having two clusters. What I was proposing was to have two kinds of nodes. One kind would have a lot of RAM and no map/reduce slots (for serving live queries with HBase), and the other would have a few map/reduce slots (for running the analytics batch queries). Replication between the two kinds of nodes would be handled by HDFS.

Comment: I got the idea about different kinds of Nodes, but I am not aware about such arrangement, although you can set different number of slots for the "MR nodes" and HBase nodes, and it will give us some kind of nodes differentiation. <br> regarding tested queries -if we have good separation of resources our HBase should not be too much affected since MR will be limited to part of cores and part of RAM. Regarding disks - i thought that logically HBase writing logs in async manner, something I will check again.

Comment: Idea of two clusters and two kinds of node was "against" my feeling of elasticity. Although my idea of memory and CPU separation is also... What will be right solution is to use some OS, which is good enough to give different quality of service to HBase and MR, but Linux is not that mature yet. I think Sun Solaris have such capabilities...